# Neo4j 'Flatten/collapse' relationship across nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that looks like the following, the grey nodes are events. The yellow nodes are components. Components depend on events and components can produce other events. Unfortunately the node labels aren't coming out clearly the picture so i added numbers

[image]

I would like to be able write a query which returns only the events (grey circles) but maintains the relationships or the actual dependencies between the events.

The end result should be another graph that looks like this:

[image]

This should work for an arbitrarily large size graph, there may be more nodes to the right off screen

User ThirstForKnowledge has kindly created the cypher to import the graph. Pasting here for visibility

```
CREATE
  (c1:Component {name: 'Comp 1'})-[:PRODUCES]->(e3:Event {name: 'Event 3'}),
  (c1)-[:PRODUCES]->(e4:Event {name: 'Event 4'}),
  (c1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(e2:Event {name: 'Event 2'}),
  (c1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(e1:Event {name: 'Event 1'}),
  (c2:Component {name: 'Comp 2'})-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(e3),
  (c3:Component {name: 'Comp 3'})-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(e3),
  (c3)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(e4),
  (e5:Event {name: 'Event 5'})<-[:PRODUCES]-(c2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have something like this in mind?

### Creating your model

For the ease of possible further answers and solutions I note my graph creating statement:

```
CREATE
  (c1:Component {name: 'Comp 1'})-[:PRODUCES]->(e3:Event {name: 'Event 3'}),
  (c1)-[:PRODUCES]->(e4:Event {name: 'Event 4'}),
  (c1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(e2:Event {name: 'Event 2'}),
  (c1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(e1:Event {name: 'Event 1'}),
  (c2:Component {name: 'Comp 2'})-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(e3),
  (c3:Component {name: 'Comp 3'})-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(e3),
  (c3)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(e4),
  (e5:Event {name: 'Event 5'})<-[:PRODUCES]-(c2);
```

[image: graph]

### Cypher statement

```
MATCH
  path = (event1:Event)<-[:PRODUCES]-(:Component)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(event2:Event)
RETURN
  event1.name AS eventUnderInspection, path;
```

### Result

```
╒══════════════════════╤═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"eventUnderInspection"│"path"                                                                           │
╞══════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"Event 4"             │[{"name":"Event 4"},{},{"name":"Comp 1"},{"name":"Comp 1"},{},{"name":"Event 1"}]│
├──────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"Event 4"             │[{"name":"Event 4"},{},{"name":"Comp 1"},{"name":"Comp 1"},{},{"name":"Event 2"}]│
├──────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"Event 3"             │[{"name":"Event 3"},{},{"name":"Comp 1"},{"name":"Comp 1"},{},{"name":"Event 1"}]│
├──────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"Event 3"             │[{"name":"Event 3"},{},{"name":"Comp 1"},{"name":"Comp 1"},{},{"name":"Event 2"}]│
├──────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"Event 5"             │[{"name":"Event 5"},{},{"name":"Comp 2"},{"name":"Comp 2"},{},{"name":"Event 3"}]│
└──────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

---

## Update to meet new requirements

### Solution

The following Cypher query enrich your existing graph by direct (flattened) relationships between depended events.

```
MATCH
  (sourceEvent:Event)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-(:Component)-[:PRODUCES]->(targetEvent:Event)
MERGE (sourceEvent)<-[:FLATTENED_DEPENDS_ON]-(targetEvent);
```

After executing the above query you can render your graph by the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH
  path = (:Event)<-[:FLATTENED_DEPENDS_ON]-(:Event)
RETURN
  path;
```

### Result

[image: graph2]

Comment: Im a bit confused is the left column the nodes and the right column the relationships?

Comment: I’ve updated the answer. In the left column you find the event under inspection, in the right column is the path between the triggering and resulting event associated. The path contains both events nodes and your requested relationships between them.

Comment: this feels like perhaps an intermediate step. Im not looking a path im expecting another graph as the output with the relationships i described in the OP

Comment: In my eyes a path is a sub graph. It contains the event nodes and requested relationships. To understand your requirements even better and to improve the answer, can you please render a fictitious result table, what I can orient myself to?

Comment: @LukeDeFeo It would have been nice if you noted `im expecting another graph` in the original question. You said `write a query which returns only the events (grey circles) but maintains the relationships or the actual dependencies between the events.` Most people read `query` and intuitively think the output will be a listing. :)

Comment: @ThirstForKnowledge i updated the question, hopefully its clearer now

Comment: I giving you an up-vote for dealing with all the changes to the question.

Comment: After seeing the updated question, I will say that was not a picture I ever would guess as being the desired answer. I was imaging lots of independent relationships in one graph.

Comment: Do you need the solution by a pure Cypher approach or is the usage of Neo4j OGM, the Neo4j [traversal framework](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/tutorial-traversal/) and/ or [user-defined functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/extending-neo4j/procedures/) valid too?

Comment: I’m open to any solution

Comment: @ThirstForKnowledge Im open to any solution

Comment: I extended my answer.